# Angular 6 context hotkeys

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I need to create context sensitive hotkeys in my angular application, for example if i had schedule entries, when i select each entry i can delete it by presing "Delete" key on the keyboard, but if i select some field inside of that entry, date, description or any other editable field i would need to have different functionality on "Delete" key, can anyone point me in the right direction at least, not sure how to manage context (or scope if you will) of the keybindings? Thank you and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a method on `(keydown)` and give a `tabindex` of each element.

**And** call a `stopPropagation()` in inner element's method to prevent event bubbling up to outer element.

html:

```
<ul (keydown)="onKeydown1($event)" tabindex="1">
  <li (keydown)="onKeydown2($event)" tabindex="1">list item1</li>
  <li>list item2</li>
</ul>
```

ts:

```
onKeydown1($event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if ($event.key === 'Delete') {
    console.log('action 1')
  }
}

onKeydown2($event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if ($event.key === 'Delete') {
    console.log('action 2')
    $event.stopPropagation()
  }
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcctnc

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me :) Do you know if this is usable with canvas? lets say entry is a drawn object in canvas, and this object selection activates some details panel via subscription on which i can change its characteristics, this wouldn't be possible with current event binding?